# 'I photographed her sing'?

Tags: usage

I have seen many times the structure 'photograph + object + -ing,' but I rarely saw 'photograph + object + infinitive.'

Do native English speakers say or write that way?

Comment: I photographed her singing means "I photographed her while she was singing" while what you put means "I photographed her as she sang". There is a subtle difference in the tense in which the form you wrote is, in my opinion, better English. But the alternative is more widely used.

Answer (score 2):

This works with certain verbs (the verb that comes first in the sentence) but not others. I wouldn’t use *photographed* like this. You can use the bare infinitive with *to watch*: “I watched her sing”. Also *to see*: “I saw her sing”. Not sure which other verbs offhand (if any) can work this way.

Comment: You can also use the bare infinitive with *to hear* ("I heard her sing"—which means something slightly different than "I heard her singing"). Also with *to feel* (although it's usually difficult to feel someone sing). *Watch*, *see*, *hear* and *feel* might be the only verbs that can be used in quite this way; in particular, similar verbs such as *observe*, *listen*, *taste* and *sense* can't be used this way.

Answer (score 2):

Photograph as a verb is used in the following two ways
Photograph somebody/something + adjective

> I refused to be photographed nude.

Photograph somebody+something doing something

> They were photographed playing with their children.

Therefore it's better to say **I photographed her singing**